# jQuery with complex selector

Tags: jquery, html, input, jquery-selectors

I have list of input control in my application. I want to find all input control, so that I have written following JS code which is working fine.

**Html**

```
<input id="txt1" value="sdgjhsgd" type="text" />
<div Class="tab active">
    <input id="txt2" value="gf5" type="text" />
    <input id="txt3" value="4r" type="text" />
    <input id="txt4" value="345" type="text" />
</div>
<div Class="tab">
    <input id="txt21" value="dfg" type="text" />
    <input id="txt31" value="56" type="text" />
    <input id="txt41" value="67" type="text" />
</div>
<div Class="tab">
    <input id="txt22" value="df" type="text" />
    <input id="txt32" value="32" type="text" />
    <input id="txt42" value="65" type="text" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var inputs = $(":input:not(input[type='hidden'])");
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cbos0wLp/5/)**

Now I want to find input controls for parent div has class name active and also input controls without parent. I have used following code but failed.

```
var inputs = $(":input:parent('div')[className='tab active']:not(input[type='hidden'])");
```

So that input has to be selected is

```
txt1
txt2
txt3
txt4
```

Comment: There's no such thing as an element without a parent, except `<html>`.

Comment: `:parent` is not for matching types of parent, it selects elements that _are_ parents, i.e. it only selects an element if it has children.

Comment: I've added selections for input withiut patent

Comment: IS this you need http://jsfiddle.net/cbos0wLp/25/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mtp6pozm/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e8eAb/61/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For selecting all the inputs inside the div with parent class 'active' use this:

```
$(".active input:not([type='hidden']");
```

For selecting the input controls without parent use the following:

```
$(".your-container > input:not([type='hidden'])");
```

the element with the class "your-container" should be the wrapper element of your posted HTML code.

Together you can use the following (not recommended, it's a long selector):

```
 $(".active input:not([type='hidden'], .your-container > input:not([type='hidden'])");
```

Answer (score 4):

> Now i want to find input controls for parent div has class name active and also input controls without parent.

Why would you want to cram all that into a single selector? jQuery selectors are not XPath, jQuery has API methods for complex traversal and filtering.

You are looking for something like:

```
var inputs = $(":input").not("[type='hidden']").filter(function () {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    return $parent.is("div.tab.active") || !$parent.is("div.tab");
});
```

Comment: Working but i dont think which is safety while changing the class name

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "safety" and by "changing the class name".

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to select all by steps:

```
var activeDiv = $('.active'); //active div

var activeInputs = $(':input:not(input[type="hidden"])', activeDiv); // inputs in div
```

And as for me it looks strange, but if you need - you can do something like:

```
var inputsWithoutTab = $('input:not([type="hidden"]):not(".tab > input")'); // To select element which is not placed into div

$.merge(activeInputs, inputsWithoutTab); // And then marge them.
alert(activeInputs.lengh); // return 4
```

Answer (score 1):

use **[filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** in jquery to retrieve the particular element

```
var input=$(".active").find("input").filter(function () {
    return !$(this).is(":hidden")

}).get();
alert(input.length);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cbos0wLp/10/)**

without parent element

```
   var input = $("input").filter(function (i, v) {     
     return (!$(this).is(":hidden") && $(this).parent().hasClass("active") || !$(v).parent().is("[class^=tab]") && !$(this).is(":hidden"))
    }).get();
alert(input.length);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cbos0wLp/30/)**

Comment: *"... and also input controls without parent ..."*

Comment: working but which is not finding the input control without parent. I want to find txt1 also.

Comment: @VigneshKumar text1 has not parent ,r u sure ?, how many input elements without parent

Comment: more than five controls has no parent

Comment: @VigneshKumar i think body is parent for that input element